# Please help me get started with modeling a solid surface fuel tank for a tractor

Tags: modeling, mesh

I need help getting started modeling this solid surface fuel tank for a tractor. I am having problems with the right to left scale while maintaining the flat bottom. Thanks.

[image: Tractor Fuel tank]

Comment: Could you mark on the mesh where you have problem and maybe add some reference image how it should look?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scaling in the y axis only? Hit `S` then `y` so that it only scales that way.

You can also try using relative scaling. If you hit `O` then `S` to scale a circle comes up that you can make larger or smaller with the middle mouse button and it will only scale within that circle.